# How do I identify which component (of many) a React warning or error refers to?

Tags: reactjs

For example, I get this in my console:

```
Warning: <some kind of React warning>
  in input (created by MyComponent)
  in form (created by MyComponent)
  ... etc
```

(In my case the warning relates to https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components, but my question is more general.)

How can I identify which `<input>` React is referring to in the stack? Is it just a hard slog through them all (in my case checking controlled vs uncontrolled), or is there a way I can get React to include a component name/id in the stack?

Comment: First of all if you're using Chrome install extension React Dev Tools

Comment: I have that. It still doesn't result in a stack trace that actually points at a specific component.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure that it has a lot of answers, but try to find the first one. The others might be broken just because of the first.

Comment: I don't quite understand. My question is about how to make the 'stack trace' more useful, or otherwise automatically find the source of the warning.